# Locking during inserting rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking, innodb

We have table

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_SUBSCRIBERS (
  SUBSCRIPTION_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Subscriber id in format MSISDN-SERVICE_ID-TIMESTAMP',
  MSISDN varchar(12) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Subscriber phone',
  STATE enum ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE', 'UNSUBSCRIBED_SMS', 'UNSUBSCRIBED_PARTNER', 'UNSUBSCRIBED_ADMIN', 'UNSUBSCRIBED_REBILLING') NOT NULL,
  SERVICE_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Id of service',
  PRIMARY KEY (SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

In parallel threads we perform actions (in java) like these

```
1. Select active subscribers
SELECT  *
    FROM  TEST_SUBSCRIBERS
    WHERE  SERVICE_ID='web-sub-1'
      and  MSISDN='000000002'
      AND  STATE IN ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE');
2. If there are no such subscribers, I can insert it
INSERT INTO  TEST_SUBSCRIBERS
                    (SUBSCRIPTION_ID, MSISDN, STATE, SERVICE_ID)
             VALUES ('web-sub-1-000000002-1504624819', '000000002', 'ACTIVE', 'web-sub-1');
```

In concurrency mode 2 threads can try to insert row with msisdn="000000002" and service-id="web-sub-1" and different subscriptionId because the current timestamp can be different. Both threads perform first select, get zero results and both insert. So we try to join these 2 queries into tranaction, but there is problem with locking for not existing rows - when we need lock for insert or something like that.
And we do not want to lock all table during this 2 actions because we suppose that our system will work too slowly in this case.
We cannot create uniq key for this situation, because for one abonent there can be multiple rows with the same unsubscribed statuses. And if we try to insert the 2 subscribers for the same service, primary key can contain timestamp with different seconds.
We tried to use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, but we get deadlock and it's heavy operation for database server.

For tests we opened 2 terminals and did step by step:

```
# Window 1
mysql> start transaction;
mysql> SELECT SUBSCRIPTION_ID FROM TEST_SUBSCRIBERS s
           WHERE s.SERVICE_ID="web-sub-1" AND s.MSISDN="000000002" FOR UPDATE;

# Window 2
start transaction;
mysql> SELECT SUBSCRIPTION_ID FROM TEST_SUBSCRIBERS s
           WHERE s.SERVICE_ID="web-sub-1" AND s.MSISDN="000000002" FOR UPDATE;

# Window 1
mysql> INSERT INTO TEST_SUBSCRIBERS
            (SUBSCRIPTION_ID, MSISDN, STATE, SERVICE_ID) 
        VALUES('web-sub-1-000000002-1504624818', '000000002', 'ACTIVE', 'web-sub-1');

# Window 2
mysql> INSERT INTO TEST_SUBSCRIBERS
              (SUBSCRIPTION_ID, MSISDN, STATE, SERVICE_ID) 
           VALUES('web-sub-1-000000002-1504624819', '000000002', 'ACTIVE', 'web-sub-1');
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock;
                    try restarting transaction
```

Is there any way to do such without deadlocks and without locking full table? Other variants that we analyzed were: 
1. separate table 
2. inserting and deleting unwanted rows.

Answer (score 3):

Plan A.  This will either insert (if necessary) or silently do nothing:

```
INSERT IGNORE ...;
```

Plan B.  This may be overkill, since nothing needs "updating":

```
INSERT INTO ...
    (...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ...;
```

Plan C.  This statement is mostly replaced by IODKU:

```
REPLACE ... (same syntax as INSERT, but it does a silent DELETE first)
```

A and B (and probably C) are "atomic", so there is no chance of a deadlock.

Comment: Thank you for replay. But in our case in on concurrency mode 2 threads can try to insert row with msisdn="000000002" and service-id="web-sub-1" and different subscriptionId because the current timestamp can be different. Both threads perform first select, get zero results and both insert. So there is no uniq key the same for 2 rows on which we can check.

Comment: @ValentinaChumak - Was that a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`?  If not, then that might be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Following answer from @RickJames.

**Plan D. Use READ-COMMITTED**

Window 1

```
mysql> set tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';
mysql> start transaction;
mysql> SELECT SUBSCRIPTION_ID FROM TEST_SUBSCRIBERS s
       WHERE s.SERVICE_ID="web-sub-1" AND s.MSISDN="000000002" FOR UPDATE;
```

Window 2

```
mysql> set tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';
mysql> start transaction;
mysql> SELECT SUBSCRIPTION_ID FROM TEST_SUBSCRIBERS s
       WHERE s.SERVICE_ID="web-sub-1" AND s.MSISDN="000000002" FOR UPDATE;
```

Window 1

```
mysql> INSERT INTO TEST_SUBSCRIBERS (SUBSCRIPTION_ID, MSISDN, STATE, SERVICE_ID) 
    VALUES('web-sub-1-000000002-10', '000000002', 'ACTIVE', 'web-sub-1');
```

Window 2

```
mysql> INSERT INTO TEST_SUBSCRIBERS (SUBSCRIPTION_ID, MSISDN, STATE, SERVICE_ID) 
    VALUES('web-sub-1-000000002-10', '000000002', 'ACTIVE', 'web-sub-1');

<begins lock wait>
```

Window 1

```
mysql> commit;
```

Window 2

```
<lock wait ends immediately>

ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'web-sub-1-000000002-10' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The duplicate key error is not a deadlock, but it's still an error. But it doesn't roll back the entire transaction, it just cancels the attempted insert. You still have an active transaction with any other changes that have been successfully executed still pending.

**Plan E. Use a queue**

Instead of having concurrent Java threads inserting to the database, just have the Java threads enter items into a message queue (e.g. ActiveMQ). Then create one Java thread to do nothing but pull items from the queue and insert them into the database. This prevents deadlocks because there's only one thread inserting to the database.

**Plan F. Embrace the deadlocks**

You can't prevent all types of deadlocks, you can only handle them when they occur. Concurrent systems should be designed to anticipate some number of deadlocks, and retry operations when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for replay. I've edited my question - it was not cleared, as I see. 2 threads can try to insert row with msisdn="000000002" and service-id="web-sub-1" and different subscriptionId (primary key,  MSISDN-SERVICE-TIMESTAMP) because subscriptionId contains the current timestamp and it can be different. What we need is just to perform select and be sure, that until we finish tranaction results of select will not be changed. if it was changed, we should rollback. I do not understand, why we get deadlock.
If we use READ COMMITED, we do not get deadlock but the both rows will be inserted.

Comment: @ValentinaChumak the deadlock occurs because of "gap locks" which are required for REPEATABLE-READ. Check out https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/ or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks or my presentation [InnoDB Locking Explained with Stick Figures](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/innodb-locking-explained-with-stick-figures).

Comment: Thanks, Bill.  (Plan E assumes only one Java client machine.)

Comment: @RickJames, right, you can make many Java clients insert into the message queue, but you must have one thread on one server pull from the queue and insert into the database.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Can multiple _machines_ share a single such message queue?  (I am thinking of Yahoo-scale, where multiple clients in multiple colocations talk to multiple MySQL servers.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, you could have multiple consumers pulling items off the queue. I believe we should be teaching developers to use the trio of technologies: cache, DBMS, message queue. Trying to use any of these in lieu of one of the others is painful.

Comment: @BillKarwin `multiple consumers pulling items off the queue` and you will be back to the concurrency issue again

Comment: @parse Have you used message queues?

Comment: @BillKarwin yes but this doesn't answer the debate :D

Comment: My experience with message queues is that they support multiple consumers. I'm not talking about a fake queue implemented in SQL. I mean RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, AWS SMS, or others. They allow multiple clients to pull the next item from a queue or a topic, without causing deadlocks.